# Kendo Widgets and Bootstrap Input-Group Addons

Tags: c#, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I am trying to add bootstrap input-group addons to either side of a kendo datepicker widget.

However as the default bootstrap theme adds rounded edges to the widget it looks strange next to the addons.

How can I remove the rounded edges from the kendo widget?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></span>
    <input id="datePicker" name="SelectedDate" type="text" value="d/MM/yyyy"  />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><input id="chkDisplayPaid" type="checkbox" /> Display Paid</span>
</div>
```

I have setup a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nw7m7pL0/4/

Here is the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Your updated JSFiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/nw7m7pL0/6/`

I have added this css in your style

```
.k-datepicker{
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}
.k-picker-wrap{
  border-radius:0px 4px 4px 0px;
}
```